# MultiBit sends BTC to different adress then I wanted

Tags: address, multibit, sending

Bug report
  Operating System: Windows 7
  MultiBit Version: 0.5.15
  Steps to replicate the problem: send BTC to specific adress
Hello I have a problem with sending BTC, what happened to me was, that when I sent BTC to my btc-e account (I used the adress they gave me for deposits), I checked everything (the amount of BTC I wanted to send and the adress) and I hit send. Problem was, that it never arrived on the adress I wanted it to and I never got my account funded. I started dealing with btc-e support, but it had not gotten me anywhere so far. But while taking screenshots as proofs I came across my transaction history.
[image: wallet]
As you can see I only used this wallet to fund my btc-e account so I sent BTC to only one adress, which is always the same (1cU8kgoVBGMxafj9ynwYjNJJH3L3PsSw7) but in those two other transactions its sent to "1cU8kgoVBGMxafj9ynwYjNJJH3L3PsSw7" (146rSpmvzyvZ4BYWCCt9fnMRLfL527CKcW) and I dont really know what that means. Except for that this adress (1cU8kgoVBGMxafj9ynwYjNJJH3L3PsSw7) never got the BTC i sent, I looked into my btc-e history and I realized that I never even got the first transaction which had this("1cU8kgoVBGMxafj9ynwYjNJJH3L3PsSw7" (146rSpmvzyvZ4BYWCCt9fnMRLfL527CKcW)) as sent to. How can I get my BTC back? I didnt do any mistake and I dont know how is this possible. 
With regards Poloch

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have put a bitcoin address in the label field in the send screen that is different to the actual address. This would explain the screen shot.

Of course it is the bitcoin address that is used to send to regardless of the label.